# Integrate iAd in UITableView with static cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to be able to integrate an iAd into the detail view of my master detail application. The detail view is a UITableView with a static table displaying some data. All of the tutorials I've found on the Internet put the iAd at the bottom of the table by using a UIView containing a UITableView. Unfortunately, I can't do that because a static table must be in a UITableView. So I'm stuck. Since this is more of a conceptual problem, I don't really have any code to post, but if you tell me what to post I can.
Thanks in advance,
Brad. :)

Answer (score 1):

i always plug in this code in the view Did Load and it places the iad right on top. see if this works and if you need the whole set of the .h and .m file let me know and i'll post it for you.

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait,ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,nil];
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
}else
{
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
}
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
```

i hope it helps and please let me know if you need the whole set of codes.
adrian

Here is a link to a tutorial that does exactly what you want also there is a example project there to show you how it works.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/16/placing-iad-banners-at-the-top-of-a-table-view.html

Comment: <img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/9axv07.png"> This is how it ends up ususally. There is a UILabel at the top of my UITableView which is now under the iAd. Sometimes a black box the exact same size as the iAd appears above it, but the iAd, instead of being where the black box is, is underneath it.

Comment: i would probably resize the tableview and the uilable to be placed below the iad box either programmatically or in IB. after all you have to leave the space open for the iad placement to appear.

Comment: Ahh. Good point. I'll do it when I get home in a few hours (:

Comment: Apparently I can't resize the UITableView. I tried "self.tableview.bounds.size.height = ..." and it says "Expression is not assignable", and I can't change it in IB either. All of these tutorials only tell you how to do this for tables inside a UIView... When the iAd is drawn on the screen at present, it sort of sticks to the table obscuring it, whereas I want the table to scroll behind it(:

Comment: I edited my answer with the link to what you're looking for. If that is your answer will you check my answer as the right one so others can get some help from it too.

Comment: I checked the link, and it was helpful because I found out what's going on. I managed to resize the tableview so there is a black box above is where the iAd will go, but the adBannerView is being added to the tableView, rather than the actual view. So [self.view addSubView:_adBannerView] is appending the adBannerView to the table, hence it covering up the content of the table and scrolling with it. I'm wondering if this is happening because I'm using storyboarding :s

Comment: I got it working! Basically, I got rid of all of the frame and origin nonsense, (well, most of it) and put in a tableViewFooter. I did try this before but I must have gone wrong somewhere because it wasn't working :L Sorry for wasting your time, but thank you for you help(:

Comment: Glad I could be of some help.